# flutter - how to show updated value in testFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using restApi to populate the form.

the code for example textFormField is like this:

```
TextFormField(
      initialValue: data.firstName, // this the data pulled from API. 
      
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
                new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
        hintText: 'First Name',
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _firstname = value;
      }),
```

I pass the data to this screen from another

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            
            builder: (context) =>myForm(snapshot.data.data[index])));
                
          //  builder: (context) => LeaveRequest()));
  },
);
```

now the problem is like I update the firstName which initially = Joe1 and I modified it to Joe2
the data is modified on the server, but in flutter screen the text field is back to Joe1.
also If I move to previous screen there also it shows joe1. if I move further back and come to the previous screen then it will pull the data from the API and show the updated data and from there in current screen I can see updated/modified data.

how I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a TextEditingController and add it to the TextFormField

```
TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
      controller: myController,
      initialValue: data.firstName, // this the data pulled from API. 
      
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
                new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
        hintText: 'First Name',
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _firstname = value;
      }),
```